# Regex to exclude specific urls

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to match URLs from my domain, but will exclude the following three URLs:

- www.mydomain.com/
- www.mydomain.com/contact
- www.mydomain.com/about

The regex should also exclude these URLs if they have query parameters. I am struggling with how to approach this problem, and any help is appreciated.

I have tried something very similar to what Rizwan posted, but as you can see, this one allows for some urls which should be excluded (like test/www.mydomain.com/)

I have also tried using negative lookaheads, but didn't get very far with that.... it was something like

```
^(www.mydomain.com)?\/(?!.*(about|contact)).*$
```

---

Comment: What is your current regex?

Comment: Please show what you tried so far, so that we can understand what you are struggling with.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using negative lookahead:

```js
url = "www.mydomain.com/contact?name=John";
result = url.match(/^www\.mydomain\.com\/(?!about$|about\?|contact$|contact\?|\?|$).*/);
console.log(result);
```

Strings starting with `www.mydomain.com/` will match if not followed by `about`, `contact`, `?`, end of line(`$`) and optional query string.

or to avoid repetitions in alternations:

```js
url = "www.mydomain.com/";
result = url.match(/^www\.mydomain\.com\/(?!(?=(?:about|contact)?(?=\?|$))).*/);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This does seem to work, at least for my purposes! Thank you SLePort, you are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are generally not the best way to parse or check URLs. You should use a URL object to parse the location, though using regexes for the individual host and pathname sections may still help, if the conditions are as specific as you require. For example:

```js
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
let output = '';
const urls = [
  'http://includeddomain.com/blarg',
  'http://includeddomain.com/blarg/anotherblarg',
  'http://includeddomain.com/about/otherstuff/',
  'http://www.includeddomain.com/blarg2',
  'http://subdomain2.includeddomain.com/blarg2/included',
  'http://includeddomain.com/contact',
  'http://includeddomain.com/about/',
  'http://anotherdomain.com/stuff',
].forEach(url => {
  const loc = new URL(url);
  const included = (
    loc.host.match(/(.*\.?)includeddomain.com/) && 
    ! loc.pathname.match(/(about|contact)(\/?)$/)
  );
  output += `<br>${loc.toString()} - ${included ? 'INCLUDED' : 'EXCLUDED'}`;
});

outputDiv.innerHTML = output;
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```